# Save "time" in a variable in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

i'm trying to write a program in GAP to obtain the time that GAP needs to construct the groups of an order given. I'm using the command:

```
ConstructAllGroups(order);;time;
```

Is there anyway to save the value of "time" in a variable?
I did it with:

```
a:=ConstructAllGroups(10);;time;
```

but only the groups were saved.

Comment: I understand why this is downvoted - this is more suitable for GAP mailing lists than for MSE. The answer is straightforward -  assign it to a variable, e.g. `t:=time;`. Beware that this is the time of the last command in the read-evaluate-print loop, i.e. between hitting <Enter> at the previous command prompt and displaying the current one. Perhaps a candidate for a GAP F.A.Q., covering also more advanced timing techniques...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is just like a variable (this is different to the time command in unix and other systems), so you can assign its value to other variables:

```
a:=ConstructAllGroups(10);;savedtime:=time;
```

Within a program I would rather refer to the value of Runtime(), that is:

```
start:=Runtime();
a:=ConstructAllPiffles(-33);
total:=Runtime()-start;
```

(community wiki so that a web search finds an answer)

Comment: Thanks and congratulations with your recent [gap badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/423/gap)! :) BTW, web search finds it anyway - community wiki has a different meaning, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).